# FixedPage doesn't have a ZIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

Im trying to print `Canvas` content and have resorted to moving the children to a `FixedPage` object to aid in positioning, etc. But I just found out it doesn't seem to have a `ZIndex` property to attach to the children.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Canvas in your fixed page something like this:

```
canvas = new Canvas();
fixedPage.Children.Add(canvas);
foreach(var element in youeElements)
{
    canvas.Children.Add(element);
    Canvas.SetZIndex(element, zindex);
}
```

Comment: @boomhauer: it is rooted in the [`Panel.ZIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) attached property, so without using a container element that respects this it will not be used.

Comment: so do items stack on top of each other in the order in which they are added?